# Change padding of a CardView programmatically

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

I came across this weird problem with the `CardView` from the compatibility library, I need to change dynamically the padding of a `CardView` but it just seems not implemented...

Here is what I found in the parent `CardView` class:

```
@Override
public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    // NO OP
}
```

I don't know the reason why but they just skipped this on the card views.

Is there any alternative to set the padding dynamically?

Comment: You can wrap `CardView` in another view, that support padding :)

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev That won't do the trick in my case, I will have to modify the margins if paddings cannot be used...

Comment: So maybe extend CardView and implement `setPadding`? And take code for it from some View class.

Comment: Yes could be a solution, but it is still weird that they did not implement that in the first place, maybe there are some problems related to the pre-Lollipop devices where the CardView padding has default values...

Comment: Maybe because they implemented `contentPadding` property? So they wouldn't to allow a double padding..

Comment: And you can see at `contentPadding` implementation to understand why setPadding was not used.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the padding of `CardView` try putting the contents of the `CardView` inside a single root layout - a `FramLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` or something.

Then change the padding of this root layout.